# Reading stdin results in an infinite loop in Intellj

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stdin

I have a problem while reading stdIn. The problem is that it never stops when executed from IntellJ with SDK Java 13. The input which I have is:

```
0 1 2
0 2 4
1 3 4
1 2 2
3 2 1
```

The code which I have is:

```java
class Vertex {
    private int label;
    private boolean visited = false;

    public Vertex(int name) {
        this.label = name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return label;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashSet<Vertex> h= new HashSet<>();
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            int s = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("s "+ s);
            h.add(new Vertex(s));
        }
        
        System.out.println("Its done");
     }
}
```

I really do not understand what is going on. When I run this in an online Java compiler it works but not in Intellj, the online compiler uses Java 1.8.

Comment: I'm not an intellij user, but do you mean you have a terminal emulator inside intellij and when you paste that input inside it it just hangs there?

Comment: Please don't make many edits after you post.  I'm trying to run your code

Comment: `scan.hasNext()` when run on `System.in` will always wait for the next input, never returns false - it won't ever "be done".

Comment: Try ctrl-D or one of the other terminal end-of-file commands to signal the stream is completed

Comment: FedericoklezCulloca, this is exactly what I do. In intellij you have a terminal emulator inside.

Comment: the actual issue is "while(scan.hasNext())"  System.in will always wait for next input. so issue is in your code its not related to intellij. if possible can you explain what you trying do?

Comment: I have a stdIn input consisting of three columns. I am trying to create a graph where the first element of the column is the source vertex, the second is the destination vertex and the third is the weight on that edge. I will ultimately read all three together.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the while loop slightly. You can insert a word to interrupt the loop. In the example it is `break`. If a number has been entered, a new vertex can be created, otherwise a help message is displayed.

```java
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    HashSet<Vertex> h = new HashSet<>();

    while (!scan.hasNext("break")) {

        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int s = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("s " + s);
            h.add(new Vertex(s));
        } else {
            System.out.printf(
                "You entered: \"%s\". Please enter a valid number or \"break\" if you want to end the loop.%n",
                scan.next());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Its done");
}
```